# how to append card dynamically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic

```js
function a()
{ 
   var a1 = "<div class=w3-container><div class=w3-card-4 w3-dark-grey style=width:25%><div class=w3-container w3-center><p>video</p><img src= ";
  var a = [ " https://image.ibb.co/cE0COF/java_mini_logo.jpg ",
       " https://preview.ibb.co/jaNQdF/marguerite_daisy_beautiful_beauty.jpg"];
  var a2= " alt=sir pic style=width:80%><p>John Doe</p></div></div></div>";
  
  var g; 
  for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
    { g= document.createElement('div');
        g.id = i;
     var abc = a1+a[i]+a2;
     document.getElementById(g.id).innerHTML=abc;
     
    }  
}
```

i am trying to make cards on user input in loop i.e 2(here) by first creating element then assigning id to it then adding code that make it card by assigning different image urls to it

Comment: `g` is already a reference to the created div, theres no need to use getElementById -> `g.innerHTML = "stuff"`

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `append` content of every `div` to `body`.

You can do this using `appendChild` method.

```js
function a()
{ 
   var a1 = "<div class=w3-container><div class=w3-card-4 w3-dark-grey style=width:25%><div class=w3-container w3-center><p>video</p><img src= ";
  var a = [ " https://image.ibb.co/cE0COF/java_mini_logo.jpg ",
       " https://preview.ibb.co/jaNQdF/marguerite_daisy_beautiful_beauty.jpg"];
  var a2= " alt=sir pic style=width:80%><p>John Doe</p></div></div></div>";
  
  var g; 
  for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
  { 
      g= document.createElement('div');
      g.id = i;
      document.body.appendChild(g);
      var abc = a1+a[i]+a2;
      document.getElementById(g.id).innerHTML=abc;         
    }  
}
a();
```